# Clojure: how to convert cons to list

Tags: clojure

`(cons 1 (list 2 3))` returns a `clojure.lang.cons`. How can I convert it to `clojure.lang.PersistentList`?

Comment: what is the purpose of this conversion first of all? In terms of clojure they are similar sequences. What is your goal? if you need to use it in some kind of conditional, using `list?` just use `seq?` instead: it works for both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `apply` the contents of the returned sequence to the `list` function:

```
(apply list (cons 1 (list 2 3)))
=> (1 2 3)
(type *1)
=> clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Comment: This solution is not idiomatic clojure code. You should use ```conj``` in this case.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of calling `cons` and trying to convert the result, use [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj):

```
(conj (list 2 3) 1)
=> (1 2 3)

(type (conj (list 2 3) 1))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Answer (score 6):

> Clojure: how to convert cons to list

Don't!

Clojure is built upon [extensible abstractions](https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming#_extensible_abstractions). One of the most important is the [sequence](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences).

I can think of no reason why you would want to convert a `cons` into a `list`or vice versa. They are both sequences and nothing much else. What you can do with one you can do with the other.

---

The above takes forward Leetwinski's comment on the question.

Comment: I agree with your answer broadly (and think it's the best offering here), but certainly there are reasons one might want a list over a sequence: for example, lists know their count, whereas for general sequences the count function may take an arbitrary amount of time. However, for someone who doesn't know how to convert a sequence to a list already, it is very hard to imagine that they actually need a list after all.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to turn it into a vector. This data type works great in Clojure. In fact, when programming in Clojure, the most of the data is kept either in vectors or maps while lists are used for "code as data" (macro system).

In your case, the solution would be:

```
user=> (vec (cons 1 (list 2 3)))
[1 2 3]
```

I don't know such a case where you need a list exactly, not a vector or a seq. Because most of the functions operate on sequences but not strict collection types. The `cons` type should also work, I believe.

If you really need a list, you may use `into` function that is to convert collections' types. But please keep in mind that when dealing with a list, the order will be opposite:

```
user=> (into '() (cons 1 (list 2 3)))
(3 2 1)
```

So you need to reverse the input data first:

```
user=> (into '() (reverse (cons 1 (list 2 3))))
(1 2 3)

user=> (type (into '() (reverse (cons 1 (list 2 3)))))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Comment: the quote is optional before empty list literal : `(= () '())`